# Why is this code crashing when large numbers are input?

Tags: c#

I'm working on the Hackerrank Minmax problem. The code I've written seems pretty efficient but it crashes if the user inputs large numbers but works with smaller numbers. I'm totally lost on where the runtime error is occurring, it has to be something to do with how I'm storing the value. Appreciate any input :) Thank you!

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Result
 {

   /*
 * Complete the 'miniMaxSum' function below.
 *
 * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
 */

  public static void miniMaxSum(List<int> arr)
  {
    int min=arr.AsQueryable().Sum()-arr.Max();
    int max=arr.AsQueryable().Sum()-arr.Min();
    Console.Write(min); Console.Write(' '); Console.Write(max);

   }

  }

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> arr = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(arrTemp 
        => Convert.ToInt32(arrTemp)).ToList();

         Result.miniMaxSum(arr);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Define large input, what is the exception you get, and at which line?

Comment: When you ask for help about "an error", please include details *about* that error, like exact error message etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't say what is a large number, but at a guess I would say that your problem could be that you are using Int32 values.

These only support a value between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`

If you want a large value, then you can use Int64 which supports values between `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` and `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

If that is still not large enough, then there is always the decimal.
If you are just dealing with positive numbers, then you can of course use the unsigned versions, which effectively doubles your maximum value.

But don't just use a data type that supports larger values if not needed, as this wastes memory and processing them takes more time (of course not really noticeable in small programs).

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types